# O que significa " Ajoujar com peso às costas "?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, palavra-para-ideia, diferenças-transatlânticas

Ajoujar é utilizado em todos países de expressão portuguesa?
"Ajoujar com peso às costas "é utilizado em que países ? É utilizado no teu país ? Qual?

Comment: Vai ser difícil encontrares resposta a isto, a pergunta parece demasiado ampla. Queres enumerar os países? Talvez assim consigas, porque então "basta" teres uma resposta "no meu país sim, é usado" para cada um dos países.

Comment: Boa sugestão! Questão editada

Comment: Não posso dizer se é usada ou não no Brasil.  Posso afirmar que nunca ouvi e nem sei o que significa "ajoujar".

Comment: @Centaurus no velho testamento a palavra "jugo" é frequente (directo da vulgata), bem como antes de haver máquinas carregava-se tudo com "parelhas de bois" aos quais se punha "o jugo". Dai "adjugo" que ao derivar para verbo perde o "d" e fica por isso irreconhecível. Mas a palavra tem a sua piada, inerente, precisamente por colocar dois "j" no mesmo vocábulo, e será por tanto que prevaleceu no léxico local Madeirense, não sem razão...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O verbo "Ajoujar" vem da palavra em latina "Adjugo", por prefixação de "Ad" com "Jugo".

A expressão "Ajoujar com o peso às costas" em Portugal é raro (o google indica que é uma palavra de uso comum na Madeira). O normal é usar a expressão:"Arcar com o peso às costas".

Comment: Ajoujar não será quando o peso é demasiado e quem o leva começa a  encolher/ abaixar' ?

Comment: Dá para os dois casos (se consultarmos o dicionário) mas como deriva da palavra "jugo" entende-se ser um "fardo muito pesado" ("jugo" também era usado para descrever servidão ou até escravidão). Portanto "carregar algo muito pesado"...